# Magnetic edges on jQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using the jQuery UI Slider component for a project as a temporal data filter, with two handles. Since the scale is very large, sometimes users have difficulty to put the handles on the limits of the slider. This cause some trouble for data which timestamp is near the limit values of the slider.

Right now I'm trying to force the slider to go automatically to the edge if the value is within a certain interval:

```
$('#slider-range').on( 'slide', function( event, ui ) {
    if( typeof ui !== 'undefined' ){

        // magnetic edges
        var magTrigger = 0.20;
        var values = $('#slider-range').slider('values');
        var min = $('#slider-range').slider('option', 'min');
        var max = $('#slider-range').slider('option', 'max');

        if(values[0] != min && values[0] - (values[0] * magTrigger) <= min) {
            $('#slider-range').slider('values', 0, min);
        }

        if(values[1] != max && values[1] + (values[1] * magTrigger) >= max) {
            $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1, max);
        }

        // typical update routines
    }
}
```

In this case, if one handle is within 20% of the respective limit, it should be considered as it is already on the limit. However, there is a visual problem, because the slider is only updates (that is, the previously updated handle goes to the limit) when I move the other handle. How can I achieve the pretended effect while the user moves the handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I think my main problems were getting the values from the wrong place and not using a suitable event. I solved like this:

```
$('#slider-range').on( 'slidestop', function( event, ui ) {
    // magnetic edges
    var magTrigger = 0.10;  // 10% of interval
    var values = ui.values;
    var min = $('#slider-range').slider('option', 'min');
    var max = $('#slider-range').slider('option', 'max');
    var interval = max - min;
    var refresh = false;

    if(values[0] <= (min + interval * magTrigger)) {
        $('#slider-range').slider('values', 0, min);
        refresh = true;
    }

    if(values[1] >= (max - interval * magTrigger)) {
        $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1, max);
        refresh = true;
    }

    if(refresh) {
         // typical update routines
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nQgL8/

Notice that now I'm getting the values from ui object and using the `slidestop` event instead of `slide`. If the handles are already inside the interval, the user is still able move them visually, but if the handles are still inside the interval, they return to the edges.

I hope this can help someone else. I didn't achieve the visual feedback (keep the handle unmoveable until be outside of the interval), but it seems to be working fine.